# Add Images to a horizontally StackPanel in XAML

Tags: c#, image, xaml, stackpanel

How exactly can I show every image that I select from my phone picture library in a `StackPanel` horizontally?

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="6"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             Margin="10,0,10,10">
        <Image Name="img"
               Height="150"
               Width="150"
               Stretch="UniformToFill" />
 </StackPanel>
```

Here is where I select a image from my phone and show it onto the xaml page.

```
 StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
 var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
 await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

 img.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Of course now evertime I select another image, this image comes in place of the previous. How can I make it so that every new selected image comes near the previous?

Comment: Create a new image and add it to the `StackPanel` control

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk how exatly?

Comment: If you want to display more images dynamically the ItemsControl should be your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pretend that the name of the `StackPanel` control is `magicStackPanel`. I assume that the code you've provided in the question works fine and I can add only the part to create a new `Image` control and add it to the `StackPanel` control.

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmapImage;
magicStackPanel.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: Yes indeed I got it! Thank you!